# Query Meteor Collection by virtual attribute

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What's the best way to query a Meteor Collection by a function on a virtual attribute, ideally without saving the attribute to the db. My collection Tasks has the following structure:

```
{
  name:"Freezer Area",
  subtasks:[
    {id:1,status:"red",name:"Unlock freezer"},
    {id:2,status:"yellow",name:"Check daily stock"},
    {id:3,status:"yellow",name:"Rotate stock"}
  ],
  managerId:curly
}
```

The virtual attribute is task status - calculated based on the status of all of its subtasks (e.g., if a single subtask is "red", the task status is "red"; else if all subtasks are "green", the task status is "green"; else the task status is "yellow").

In one of my templates, I'd like to display only tasks of a single status. What kind of client side query can I run on the Meteor Collection? Is there a recommended way to avoid re-calculating task status every time these templates are rendered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually to do what you would like [map-reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) would be the best option, it would store its results in a seperate collection which can avoid the need to recalculate. However meteor hasn't implemented map-reduce in its version of mini-mongo.

A better option to meteor's constraints would be to recalculate its status and update it in the collection when a task's state is altered, so that it needs no redundant recalculation on every non updating query.

You could also post process the data. Its a bit messy, but you get the idea

```
results = virtualize_status(Collection.find({}).fetch());


//this function goes through and adds the status
function virtualize_status(results) {
    var totalresults = results.length, element = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = results[i];
        green = 0;
        red = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < element.subtasks.length; j++) {
           if(element.subtasks[j].status == "green") {
               green++;
           }
           else if(element.subtasks[j].status == "red") {
               red++;
           }
        }

        final_status = "yellow";

        if(red > 0) {
            final_status = "red";
        }
        else if(green == element.subtasks.length) {
            final_status = "green"
        }

        results[i]["status"] = final_status;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, the virtual attribute should be reactive.

Comment: In both use cases it would be, the function processes it because the collection is reactive and is its input. In the second use-case its not technically virtual but it would also be reactive because when the collection is changed, clients are pushed the new data with the updated status.

Comment: By "second use-case", I assume you mean the code example you provided. That is not reactive since I'd have to explicitly call the virtualize_status function new data is pushed to the client. I am trying out your initial suggestion of saving the derived attribute to mongo. It works of course, and I can publish additional custom collections (e.g., counts of tasks grouped by status) from the server directly. It's the Meteor way I suppose.

Comment: You wouldn't have to call the virtualize_status function on its own unreactively. You could simply put it in a reactive context such as `Template.a.y = function() { .. virtualize_status(Collection.find({}).fetch());.. }` because you're going to call the reactive `Collection.find({...})` anyway, the data is modified after the data has been sent down to the client